# WinAppDriver and Appium - send.keys() sending a '#' in place of ''\'

Tags: python, appium, winappdriver

I'm having trouble with sending a backslash character using WinAppDriver and Appium. When I use send.keys to send a backslash character, a '#' character is sent in it's place.
I have tried in numerous ways (shown below).

Appium v 0.28

WinnAppDriver v 1.1.1809.18001

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {'app': 'Root', 'autoLaunch': 'false'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723',
                               desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
w1 = driver.find_element_by_name('Untitled - Notepad')
for elem in w1.find_elements_by_name('Text Editor'):
    elem.send_keys(chr(92))
    elem.send_keys('\\')
    elem.send_keys(r'C:\test')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is currently a bug. (Read more about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/507) for example.)

You cannot send `\` as a string if you don't use US keyboard layout. For a dirty workaround, you can type the character via it's ASCII code by pressing ALT, then the numbers 9 and 2, then releasing ALT, as is being described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/194#issuecomment-412984691):

```
Keys.Alt + Keys.NumberPad9 + Keys.NumberPad2 + Keys.Alt
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work on a SaveAs dialog window when setting the path if num lock isn't active (as the 2 key is a shortcut on the SaveAs dialog). Tried on Windows 11 on a WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

Using a UK Keyboard and Windows 11  and C#, I had this problem. I tried to populate a Textbox with a Windows filepath which had several sub-folders:-

- Using String.Normalize() - no luck, # remained a #
- Inserting the Unicode for Backslash (u005C) - it got converted to #

The solution was to temporarily switch to a US Keyboard by defining 2 cultures, a US one and a UK one:-

```
CultureInfo CultureInfoUS = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( "en-US" );
CultureInfo CultureInfoUK = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( "en-UK" );
```

and then bracketing the Appium .SendKeys() methods on the way in with:

```
InputLanguage.KeyBoardLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(CultureInfoUS);
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = KeyBoardLanguage;
```

so that my keyboard was a US one, and on the way out with:

```
InputLanguage.KeyBoardLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(CultureInfoUK);
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = KeyBoardLanguage;
```

so that my keyboard was reset to a UK one.